# Mac M1 Spyder : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'

Tags: python, python-import, lxml, spyder, python-3.9

I am using Mac M1 now, when I am trying to import lxml in my python code, it shows below:

[image]

I've tried

my Python version is : Python 3.9.12

my lxml version is: 4.9.1
[image]

Comment: Seems like you are using the Spyder standalone version for MacOS. To use packages outside the ones that come bundled with the installer you need to follow the instructions that are available at the Spyder docs FAQ page to set the custom interpreter preference: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment and https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-packages-installer

Comment: Hi @DanielAlthviz ,you are right, i am using standalone Spyder app, the reason is I installed anaconda, but I can't find anaconda navigator, so I can't launch Spyder inside anaconda. Do u know how to find anaconda navigator on Mac M1

Comment: Not sure about where to find Anaconda navigator, sorry. However if you want to launch Spyder you can do it by running from the terminal `spyder` (if your base env has Spyder installed). Also, If you want to get the latest Spyder version with conda and also the `lxml` package you should create a new env with conda-forge packages. For that you can run from a terminal something like: `conda create -n spyder-cf -c conda-forge spyder lxml`. Then, to use the new env, `conda activate spyder-cf` and finallyto  run Spyder `spyder`

Comment: Hi @DanielAlthviz , i think my issue is my standalone spyder can't find 'lxml' package, how can i link them together？ coz i am sure 'lxml' is installed

Comment: Seems like you find your way to setup Spyder with the wiki :). Did you find the wiki more clear than the Spyder Docs FAQ page @Sky ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason Spyder can't find 'lxml' is I used standalone Spyder, in order to fix this, I have to use a separate environment.

1 - Follow below article to create a new virtual environment
https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment

2 - Follow below article to install necessary packages in the new environment, which link to Spyder IDE later, all issues will be fixed.
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder#installing-packages-into-the-same-environment-as-spyder

Answer (score 0):

Your development environment may be using a different Python installation. Run `python -c "import lxml"` in the same shell where you ran `pip install ...`. If that works, then configure your development environment (there is an FAQ link on your screenshot).

It may also happen that `pip` and `python` belong to different Python installations. To fix it, use `python -m pip install ...` instead of `pip install ...`.

For example, if you run `python -m pip install lxml`, that should install *lxml*, then running `python -c "import lxml; print('OK')"` should display *OK*.

Comment: I've tried all command you mentioned, seems not working ....T.T

Comment: If you just say *not working* without giving any details (which command you tried, copy-paste the command and its output), it's impossible to help any further. You may want to update your question with the details.

Comment: For example, if you run `python -m pip install lxml`, that should install *lxml*, then running `python -c "import lxml; print('OK')"` should display *OK*.

Comment: Hi @pts ,if you check my 2nd screenshot, u will see that I've installed lxml successfully. the issue is when I "import lxml", it says: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'"

Comment: Still, the most relevant and most useful advice I can give is what I've already written.

Comment: Hi @pts, I finally figured out. I installed standalone Spyder. I need to use a separate environment for packages.